# How to measure amount of transfered megabytes on a website?

Tags: web-services

I have website and I plan to duplicate it for another communities and I need to find out the average traffic for that one site (eventuelly for the others). With which tool I can measure amount of transfered MB(GB..). I'm using google analytics, but I can't find it there. My server is linux based with apache web server. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that can parse Apache log, but I forgot the name. Your host may be providing such a tool.

Otherwise you can do this :

```
cat /var/log/httpd/access_log | awk '{ SUM += $5} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }'
```